# Unable to activate any other elements during loop (iPhone app)

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, toggle

I am implementing a UISwitch button on my iPhone app. When the switch is on, the phone should vibrate and play a sound. When the switch is turned off, the vibrate and sound should cease. When I turn the switch on, I am unable to do anything and the phone continues to vibrate and emit sound. I cannot press any other buttons, probably because of the while loop. Here is my function:

```
- (IBAction)toggleVibrate:(id)sender {
    if([sender isOn]){
        //vibrate and play sound until toggled
        while(true) {
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

            SystemSoundID mySSID;

            NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"wav"];
            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain([NSURL fileURLWithPath: path]), &mySSID);

            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySSID);
        };
    }else{
        //kill vibration and sound

    }
}
```

Any ideas on how I am able to kill the vibration and sound?

Comment: Infinite loops on the main thread are generally a bad thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're blocking the main thread (also called UI thread). You should run that loop in a separate thread or queue. Try something like this:

```
- (IBAction)toggleVibrate:(id)sender {
    static dispatch_queue_t my_queue = nil;

    if(my_queue == nil)
        my_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.yourorg.vibrate_queue", NULL);

    if([sender isOn]){
        //vibrate and play sound until toggled
        dispatch_async(my_queue, ^{
            while([sender isOn]) {
                AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

                SystemSoundID mySSID;

                NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"wav"];
                AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain([NSURL fileURLWithPath: path]), &mySSID);

                AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySSID);
            };
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, the sound plays even after the user presses the home button.

Comment: @rmaddy To be honest, I never played any sound on my apps. But I don't see any reason why it should fail in a background queue/thread. @Ralph I didn't expect that :) but the developer could "fix" that by handling notifications such as `applicationDidBecomeActive:` and `applicationWillResignActive:`.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is really obvious :

```
while(true) { }
```

This loop will never exit. Never. All code execution is completely be stopped (stuck in the infinite loop, playing the sound over and over again) and you `toggleVibrate:` method is never returning.

Try working with a `NSTimer` instead that fires the sound playing, and stopping/starting it in your `toggleVibrate:` methods